# App may need approval for background location

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

I have received an email from google that one of my apps needs to change the location permission from background to foreground....

I took a look at the app and it seems that is already on foreground... my permissions on my manifest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also I request the permission on user demand... What is the problem, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#foreground) you will find in which scenario you need foreground permissions.

In the link it clearly says:

> If your app contains a feature that shares or receives location
> information only once, or for a defined amount of time, then that
> feature requires foreground location access. Some examples include the
> following:
>
> - Within a navigation app, a feature allows users to get turn-by-turn directions.
> - Within a messaging app, a feature allows users to share their current location with another user.

On Android 10 (API level 29) and higher, you must declare this foreground service type.

```
<service
    android:name="MyNavigationService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location" ... >
    <!-- Any inner elements would go here. -->
</service>
```

Comment: What is "MyNavigationService"? It says :     Unresolved class 'CompassService'

    Class referenced in the manifest, com.thors.compass.CompassService, was not found in the project or the libraries

Comment: You can follow this link : https://thakkarkomal009.medium.com/update-location-in-background-using-foreground-service-android-7aee9de1a6d6 for creating a foreground service which fetches location info. Just replace "MyNavigationService" with your foreground service name.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that tutorial uses kotlin code which do not integrate well on my java app....